# is it possible to cache data from server side with react-query and nextjs?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, next.js, react-query

I am new to react-query and my webapp uses nextjs with firebase. I have few pages (projects.jsx and [id],jsx) that solely depend on prefetched data from server side. However, they are fetching data from exactly the same api route.

I was hoping using react query within getStaticProps would cache the results and from there I can send the data onto client side. But from what all I tried, it seems the caching happens on client side only like when I call

```
useQuery("projects", () => fetch("/projects"), {
  initialData: projects //assume projects contains all the projects from getStaticProps()
})
```

But doing so defeats the purpose of minimizing async calls to firebase from server side. So, is there a way to achieve caching in server side or is getStaticProps() the only option?

Answer (score 1):

I think your approach with `initialData` should work, and is also outlined [in the docs](https://react-query.tanstack.com/guides/ssr#using-initialdata). Further, in [this section of the docs](https://react-query.tanstack.com/guides/ssr#staleness-is-measured-from-when-the-query-was-fetched-on-the-server), it states that:

> Because staleTime defaults to 0, queries will be refetched in the background on page load by default. You might want to use a higher staleTime to avoid this double fetching, especially if you don't cache your markup.

And I guess this is what is happening for you. To prevent that, setting a higher `staleTime` is likely what you want. If you provide `initialData` with `staleTime: Infinity`, the data will not be refetched at all (unless the query is garbage collected).

Comment: I did add staleTime but it seems the queryFn re runs everytime on the server side regardless. So I guess only getStaticProps will have to do for my case.

Comment: Yes, in getServerSideProps, it will run every time